# Declare a class and member variables using macros in C++

Tags: c++, class, macros, preprocessor

I would like to use preprocessor macros to declare many classes like the following:

```cpp
class ClassA : public ClassBase
{
public:
    int a;
    float b;
    char c;

    std::vector<void *> fun()
    {
        /*
         Code that uses all member variables
        */
        std::vector<void *> v{&a, &b, &c};
        return v;
    }
};
```

For example, the same class declared with macros may look something like this:

```
BEGIN_CLASS(ClassA)
    MEMBER(int, a)
    MEMBER(float, b)
    MEMBER(char, c)
END_CLASS(ClassA)
```

or (@Peter, thanks for ruling out above option)

```
NEW_CLASS(ClassA, int, a, float, b, char, c)
```

The only parts of the declaration that will change are class name, member variable names, member variable type and number of member variables. Everything else will follow the same template.

In my application, users will need to declare classes like this regularly and I would like to provide a simpler interface for them.

Regardless of whether this is good practice, I'd like to know if declaring a class like this is possible and if so, how?

Comment: For some reason this reminds me of wxWidgets and why not to use macros.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bad idea. Sorry. What problem are you _really_ trying to solve?

Comment: When Google was faced with this problem, they created their own simple markup language and a preprocessor that could read the user-supplied markup and generate the necessary header files ( https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview ).  Perhaps you want to do something similar; I think trying to implement this using just preprocessor macros is going to end badly for all involved.

Comment: *"I would like to provide a simpler interface for them."* The original C++ syntax(without macros) seems simpler and clearer to me TBH.

Comment: It seems like you want a tuple (or tuple-like).

Comment: So, your users can change everything except the keywords? Then, what would be simpler with your macros? They just act as keywords, except that they obscure the code.

Comment: I agree with all of your comments. In fact, I alluded to the fact that it may be a bad idea in my question. But I am still curious. @Dúthomhas, the problem is already solved by writing classes manual, I would just like to provide a more concise way for declaring such classes.

Comment: @j6t, I agree that it would obscure the code, but it would make the code more concise and users don't need to remember the name of base class and name of function to override.

Comment: But they need to remember names of our macros. In practice, they will copy and paste from existing code, be it from production or from an example. Whether they do that with your macros or with actual C++ code does not matter.

Comment: @j6t, I absolutely agree. I guess I'm just curious to know if something like this can be done.

Comment: The short response is that macros cannot be set up as you describe, because macros work by doing text substitution on source code and don't offer a turing complete programming engine.   To work as you require, `MEMBER` would somehow need to set up data structures AT PREPROCESSING TIME that would be conditionally used by `END_CLASS` (e.g. to emit the definition of `fun()`) and the preprocessor does not support such things.   As mentioned by Jeremy, you would need to set up some dynamic code generation - which is beyond capability of the C or C++ preprocessor.

Comment: @Peter, I see your point, but correct me if I'm wrong, it is only valid for the first type of macro that I proposed. The second macro type should have all of the required information to construct the class. It just needs to be made variance to cope with and arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: You are after something that resembles the MFC or ATL message map macros.  I am not sure but you could implement yours the same way.  Here is some documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/cpp/atl/reference/com-map-macros   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8766/C-Class-Mapping-An-XML-Parser-example

Comment: Thank @JerryJeremiah, this looks very interesting. I'll have to give it a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define NEW_CLASS(name_, seq_) \
    class name_ : public ClassBase \
    { \
      public: \
        IMPL_NEW_CLASS_end(IMPL_NEW_CLASS_decl_loop_a seq_)\
        \
        std::vector<void *> fun() \
        { \
            return { IMPL_NEW_CLASS_end(IMPL_NEW_CLASS_list_loop_a seq_) }; \
        } \
    };

#define IMPL_NEW_CLASS_end(...) IMPL_NEW_CLASS_end_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define IMPL_NEW_CLASS_end_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_end

#define IMPL_NEW_CLASS_decl_loop_a(...) ::std::type_identity_t<__VA_ARGS__> IMPL_NEW_CLASS_decl_loop_b
#define IMPL_NEW_CLASS_decl_loop_b(name_) name_; IMPL_NEW_CLASS_decl_loop_a
#define IMPL_NEW_CLASS_decl_loop_a_end

#define IMPL_NEW_CLASS_list_loop_a(...) IMPL_NEW_CLASS_list_loop_b
#define IMPL_NEW_CLASS_list_loop_b(name_) &name_, IMPL_NEW_CLASS_list_loop_a
#define IMPL_NEW_CLASS_list_loop_a_end


NEW_CLASS(ClassA, (int)(a) (float)(b) (char)(c))
```

I've used the `(a)(b)(c)` syntax for lists, because AFAIK only those lists can be traversed without generating a bunch of repetitive boilerplate macros. (can't do that with `a, b, c`)

I've wrapped the type in `std::type_identity_t<...>` to allow arrays, function pointers, etc (`int[4] x;` is invalid, but `std::type_identity_t<int[4]> x;` is ok).

I chose this specific syntax because the types can contain commas, so e.g. `(type,name)(type,name)` wouldn't be viable, because it's tricky to extract the last element from a comma-separated list (consider `(std::map<int,float>,x)`, which counts as a comma-separated list with 3 elements).

`(name,type)(name,type)`, on the other hand, would be viable (extracting the first element of a list is simple), but it doesn't look as good. If you go for this syntax, note that the loops still have to use at least two macros each (`_a` and `_b` in my example), even if the two would be the same (a single-macro loop doesn't work because of the ban on recursive macros). The loops would also need two `_end` macros each, not one.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is great! I noticed this solution requires C++20. Do you know if something like this can be done in C++ 17 or lower without having to make a lot of boilerplate macros as I have done in my solution?

Comment: @Andrew You mean `std::type_identity_t<...>`? You can replace it with `std::enable_if_t<true, ...>`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution by following this post:
[Variadic macros tricks](https://codecraft.co/2014/11/25/variadic-macros-tricks/)

Here's what I did.

STEP1:
Define macro templates. One for all the number of member variables you will to support

```
#define _NEW_CLASS_1(name, t1, v1)      \
    struct name : public ClassBase{     \
        t1 v1;                          \
        std::vector<void *> fun(){      \
            std::vector<void *> v{&v1}; \
            return v;                   \
        }                               \
    };

#define _NEW_CLASS_2(name, t1, v1, t2, v2)   \
    struct name : public ClassBase{          \
        t1 v1;                               \
        t2 v2;                               \
        std::vector<void *> fun(){           \
            std::vector<void *> v{&v1, &v2}; \
            return v;                        \
        }                                    \
    };

#define _NEW_CLASS_3(name, t1, v1, t2, v2, t3, v3) \
    struct name : public ClassBase{                \
        t1 v1;                                     \
        t2 v2;                                     \
        t3 v3;                                     \
        std::vector<void *> fun(){                 \
            std::vector<void *> v{&v1, &v2, &v3};  \
            return v;                              \
        }                                          \
    };

// define more if you need to support more member variable
```

STEP2:
Use variadic macros to select one of the above macros to build the class. Add more arguments following the pattern to support more than member variables.

```
#define _GET_OVERRIDE(cls, t1, v1, t2, v2, t3, v3, t4, v4, NAME, ...) NAME
#define NEW_CLASS(...) _GET_OVERRIDE(__VA_ARGS__, _NEW_CLASS_4, _, _NEW_CLASS_3, _, _NEW_CLASS_2, _, _NEW_CLASS_1, _)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

STEP3:
Declare classes using `NEW_CLASS` macro.

```
NEW_CLASS(ClassA,
          int, a,
          float, b)

NEW_CLASS(ClassB,
          std::string, str,
          int, n,
          double, d)

NEW_CLASS(ClassC,
          double, c)

int main()
{

    ClassA objA;
    ClassB objB;
    ClassC objC;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of boilerplate macros. :(